# usage of double pointers as arguments

Tags: c, double-pointer

Please find the code snippet as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int My_func(int **); 

int main() 
{ 
     int a =5;
     int *p = &a;
     My_Func(&p);
     printf("The val of *p is %d\n",*p);
}

void My_Func(int **p)
{
     int val = 100;
     int *Ptr = &val;
     *p = Ptr;
}
```

How does using a double pointer as an argument in `my_Func` function and also making a change of value, both reflect the same in the main function? If we use a single pointer in `My_Func`, why does that not change the value in main? Please explain this for me with examples if possible.

Comment: As a side note, don't return pointers to local variables. When you've returned from a function, its local variables are not valid anymore.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @meaning-matters: I just wanted to know why arguments as double pointers reflect the value in main when changed in the My_func definition?

Answer (score 8):

`int **p` is a pointer to a pointer-to-int. `My_Func(int **p)` works by changing the value of integer that the pointer-to-int points to i.e. `int a`.

Without changing the implementation, the function will not work with a pointer-to-int parameter `int *p` as there is a second level of indirection. In addition, you're setting the value to a local variable that is created on the stack. When the function is completed the memory used for the variable will be reclaimed, therefore making the value of `a` invalid.

```
void My_Func(int **p)
{
     int val = 100; // Local variable.
     int *Ptr = &val; // This isn't needed.
     *p = Ptr;
} // val dissapears.
```

Remove the second level of indirection and copy `val` by value instead of pointing to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void My_Func(int *p) 
{
    int val = 100;
    *p = val;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 5;
    My_Func(&a);
    printf("The val of a is %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In short, in C when you pass something as a parameter, a *copy* will be passed to the function. Changing the copy doesn't affect the original value.

However, if the value is a pointer, what it *points to* can be changed. In this case, if you want to affect the pointer, you need to pass *a pointer to it* down to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the address of local variable, which will soon disappear when My_Func returns. You can use following in your code. However you can do the same thing just by using single pointer, double pointer is not required in this example.

```
void My_Func(int **p)
{
     int val = 100;
     int *Ptr = &val;
     **p = *Ptr;
}
```

Comment: I am late here, hope you don't mind I ask: I have the exact problem, I tried passing both single and double pointers and change the value within a function, in both cases, the original values did get changed. My understanding is that we need to use a double pointer to change the original value within a function. Hope you could shred some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use it in the function declaration:

```
void func(int *p)
{
  int val =100;
  int *temp=&val;
  p=temp;
 }
```

p starts pointing to another address i.e. address of val. So it will print the value 100.

Important note: Try it in your downloaded compiler (always in case of pointers) not in the online compiler. The online compiler doesn´t keep track of lost addresses in stack.